# How to show image in pdf page using TCPDF?

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

Please find the below code. When i print_r() the output, image shows in the webpage. But image is not showing in the PDF page. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code?

```
$link = base_url();
    foreach($defect_photos as $defect_photo){
    $html1 .= "<td><img src='$link/uploads/defects/$defect_photo' border='0' height='500' width='500' align='right'></td>";
    }
    $html1 .= '</tr></table>';
    //print_r($html1);
    //exit;
    $pdf->writeHTML($html1, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, it is an absolute path. When print_r() and exit the output, the image is showing but not when view it in the PDF page

Answer (score 2):

Using this line of code you can add image on tcpdf. or in details you can visit https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_009/

$pdf->Image('images/image_demo.jpg', '', '', 40, 40, '', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above method but image is not appearing in the PDF. so, I used html image.

Comment: `foreach($defect_photos as $defect_photo){
              $pdf->Image(base_url().'/uploads/defects/$defect_photo', '', '', 40, 40, '', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
            }` I tried this code but no response.

Comment: when i fetch image  from the database, it is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

i have also same issue but i rectified my issue by giving relative path to the image instead of giving the base_URL() or absolute path have a look below code what i add .It should be helpful.

```
<?php $imgs=$results->image4; 
    foreach($imgs as $im){  ?>
    <td><img src="<?php echo 'uploads/images/'.$im ?>" /></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: ya sure buddy and let me know

Comment: @MN you need not to give "base_url()"  in image path just gave folder path thats it because we gave already a file directory so let u try this thing i get image from database.so i gave these solution for you.